# Return duplicate names (including partial matches)

Tags: excel, powershell

Excel guy here that occasionally turns to automating [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) via vba.

I tried to solve https://stackoverflow.com/q/36538022/641067 (now closed) and couldn't get there with my basic powershell knowledge and googlefu alone.

In essence the problem the OP presented is:

1. There are a list of names in a text file.
2. Aim is to capture only those names that occurr at least once (so discard unique names, see point (3)).
3. Names occurring at least once include partial matches, ie *Will* and *William* can be considered duplicates and should be retained. Whereas *Bill* is not a duplicate of *William*.

I tried various approaches including

- `Group`
- `Compare-Object` *see example below*

But I was stymied by part (3). I suspect that a loop is required to do this but am curious whether there is a direct `Powershell`approach,

Looking forward to hearing from the experts.

*what I tried*

```
$a = Get-Content "c:\temp\in.txt"
$b = $a | select -unique
[regex] $a_regex = ‘(?i)(‘ + (($a |foreach {[regex]::escape($_)}) –join “|”) + ‘)’
 $c = $b -match $a_regex
 Compare-object –referenceobject $c -IncludeEqual $a
```

Comment: Do you consider *Andrew* and *Allice* to be duplicates? Or in other words, how much should the LCS or similarity be?

Comment: If one text field fits completely as is inside the other (starting from LHS) then you can consider it a dupe. So Will is a duplicate of William, but Bill is not.

Comment: According to those rules, you could sort the list and output the search results of following regex: `^(\w+)$\n\1` to retain only the duplicates.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers can you pls add the regexp optio as a separate approach  to your loop answer. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following testscript using a loop would work for the rules you outlined and looks foolproof to me

```
$t = ('first', 'will', 'william', 'williamlong', 'unique', 'lieve', 'lieven')
$s = $t | sort-object

[String[]]$r = @()
$i = 0;
while ($i -lt $s.Count - 1) {
    if ($s[$i+1].StartsWith($s[$i])) {
        $r += $s[$i]
        $r += $s[$i+1]
    }
    $i++
}
$r | Sort-Object -Unique
```

and following testscript using a regex might get you started.

```
$content = "nomatch`nevenmatch1`nevenmatch12`nunevenmatch1`nunevenmatch12`nunevenmatch123"

$string = (($content.Split("`n") | Sort-Object -Unique) -join "`n")
$regex = [regex] '(?im)^(\w+)(\n\1\w+)+'
$matchdetails = $regex.Match($string)
while ($matchdetails.Success) {
    $matchdetails.Value
    $matchdetails = $matchdetails.NextMatch()
}
```

Comment: This is excellent - many thanks. As a side note shouldn't *nunevenmatch123* also been a match?

Comment: Yes, it should but that's the problem with the regex solution. If you add an uneventmatch1234, you'll see that that solution returns the correct result *(as there are now an even number of matches)*. I have not yet been able to figure out how to work around that problem.

Comment: The regex engine finds a match *(containing two lines) and proceeds searching after the end of the match ...

Comment: ... posted an updated version that so far matches *(pun intented)* the expectations.